# How to copy and paste data from excel to another excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to copy excel data from source excel file to destination excel file. However, I am not just simply copy whole data from source file.

I need keep copying ONLY certain rows and columns like the first 5 rows by 4 columns (this data covered, row: 1st to 5th, column: A to D) from source file and paste on fixed coordination of destination excel file like row: 3rd to 7th, column: A to D. Next iteration I would like to copy the next 5 rows by 4 columns (this data covered, row: 6th to 10th, column: A to D) to same coordination (row: 3rd to 7th, column: A to D) and keep copying from source file until finish copy whole data from source file.

Below is the attachments of source file and desired destination file.

[image: source excel file]
above figure shows data from source file

[image: desired destination excel file]
above figure shows data from destination file

Here is the code that I have tried, but it returns weird output:

```
        # source          
        filename ="C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/combine_all.xlsx"
        wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename) 
        ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]                         
        # destination
        filename1 ="C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/algorithm.xlsx"
        wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1) 
        ws2 = wb2.active                           
        mr = ws1.max_row 
        mc = ws1.max_column  
        try:                     
            m = [1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 66, 71, 76, 81, 86, 91, 96, 101, 106, 111, 116, 121, 126, 131, 136]
            n = [6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 66, 71, 76, 81, 86, 91, 96, 101, 106, 111, 116, 121, 126, 131, 136, 141]
            for q in range (3, 8):
                for xm, yn in zip(m, n):                             
                    for i in range (xm, yn): 
                        for j in range (1, 5): 
                            c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)                                    
                            ws2.cell(row = q, column = j).value = c.value
```

Appreciate a lot if anyone could help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: The destination shown is 3rd to 7th (not 8th). Why copy to the same range, the result will just be the last 20 cell block copied ?

Comment: Ya, the destination is 3rd to 7th row, sorry for my typo, what I am trying to do is copy 1st to 5th row from source and paste to the fixed destination (which is 3rd to 7th row), then copy again but different row from 6th to 10th row from source and paste on the fixed destination (which is 3rd to 7th row) again, then copy again but different row 11th to 15th from source and paste on the fixed destination (which is 3rd to 7th row), and so on

Comment: The source file is actually not just 15 rows by 4 columns, it is more than one hundred rows by 4 columns

Comment: I just edited my post, sorry for the typo of '3rd to 8th'.

Comment: my question was why copy TO the same range, I understand the FROM range changes ? each copy will erase the result of the previous one,

Comment: do you refer 'same range' to same column like A to D or same row which five rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are copying to the same destination range each time but try this

```py
#!python
import openpyxl as xl

COPY_ROWS = 5
COPY_COLS = 4  
FOLDER = 'C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/'

# source          
filename1 = 'combine_all.xlsx'
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(FOLDER + filename1) 
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]                         

#destination
filename2 = 'algorithm.xlsx'
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(FOLDER + filename2) 
ws2 = wb2.active                           

r = 0
i = 1
count = 0
while r < ws1.max_row:
    r += 1
    for c in range(1, COPY_COLS+1):
        for i in range(0,COPY_ROWS):
           ws2.cell(i+3,c).value = ws1.cell(i+r,c).value
    count += 1
    r += i

wb1.close    
wb2.save(FOLDER + "algorithm1.xlsx")  
wb2.close

print("{} blocks of {} rows by {} columns copied".format(count,COPY_ROWS,COPY_COLS))
```

Comment: Your answer is works for me, thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again, may I ask few question regarding the code?

Comment: 1. Why you want to use 'COPY_COLS+1' instead of 'COPY_COLS' at 'for c in range(1, COPY_COLS+1):'

Comment: 2. Why you use 'r += 1' instead of 'r += 3' after 'while r < ws1.max_row:'?

Comment: 3. What is the usage of 'count = 0'?

Comment: @edison (1) range(1,5) gives you the numbers 1,2,3,4. (2) r+=1 is to increment row to new block, (3) count =0 is used in a  message at the end - see updated code

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/combine_all.xlsx"
input = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
input.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

see this [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/excel-and-pandas/)

Comment: Don't the restrictions described (_However, I am not just simply copy whole data from source file, I need to copy ONLY certain rows and columns_) rule out this solution?

Comment: I think this solution is not actually answer on my question, but thanks Zouhair Elhadi's effort